# Total sum not working inside the for-each-group tag in BI Publisher

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I have the following template I am trying to upload-

[image]

This is giving me an output like - 
[image]

This should come like -

[image]

How can i change the RTF template  to get the desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1: Ending with incorrect tags**

You are beginning with a `<?for-each-group?>` but ending with an `<?end for-each?>`. Change to `<?end for-each-group?>`.

**Problem 2: Merged/Split cells**

"For" loops should be for an entire row. They get really messy and unpredictable when you use them with merged and/or split cells. You can nest the for loops inside one another, but make sure they include entire line. Like this:
[image]